# What's the theoretical maximum amount of war assets that can be acquired?

Tags: mass-effect-3

And to make it simple, let's say it's for a non-imported game without DLC.

The reason I ask is Bioware told me I'd be able to finish the game and get the best ending without needing multiplayer or the iOS apps.  However, I'm still about 3000 short of the best ending without increasing Galactic Readiness, yet I've been fairly meticulous.  I'm sure I've gotten most, if not all, of the Citadel missions, and I even managed to unite the quarians and geth.  In fact, the only thing left in my mission list is find intel on Eden Prime, but that's essentially locked out after waking Javik.

So, if I were to go through the game and make all the best choices, what would be my Total Military Strength (TMS)?

Comment: My Total War asset is about 7200 and i think the most you can get is 7300 and I picked the Green ending =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just did a quick count through the wiki, and I got 6500 +/- 200 for non-DLC non-imported character options.  I may have accidentally counted some mutually exclusive options.  That gives an EMS of around 3000.

> Not enough to get the "Shepard Lives" ending(4000), but certainly enough for synthesis(2800)

Comment: This meshes with my own eyeballing. I was waiting to answer until I could add it all up, but this is close enough for government work.

Comment: Did you remember to count War Assets acquired directly through scanning?

Comment: @MBraedley Yes, this number should include those from what I can see.

Comment: I guess this means that a) I didn't miss much and b) Bioware lied to me.

Comment: If anyone wants to check my decisions, you can get awfully close. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmsYTS1wvgPwdG5iX3FWX2M2UW9Pd1dBSC1hU005V3c Numbers are pulled from coalesced.bin, with the right decisions throughout the series + DLC I got to 7942 TMS, which is 3971 EMS. I'm pretty sure I messed up a few <10 TMS choices, but not enough to cover 60.

Comment: @ampersand pretty sure the difference would come from importing a wrex dead, data never seen save, allowing you to get both the Krogan and Salarians. Which is... An awfully rare import condition.

Comment: My results thus far are *pretty* close to Ampsersand's, where I'll fall just shy of 4,000 effective.  I've been doing my best to 100% everything, and I imported a pretty "ideal" ME2 save.  BioWare's full of it if they think you can get to the highest tier endings without doing something other than single player.

Comment: I think it's consensus that you can't even come close w/o imports and DLC.

Comment: @Stephen: Although I imported a character and have From Ashes, I asked about a non-imported character and no DLC specifically because it provides the best baseline for everyone.  If the baseline ended up being higher than my TMS, then I know I did something wrong.

Comment: @agent86 it's *possible* with nothing but single player, you need to manufacture a 'perfect' imported save. Hmmm I think I have my next project.

Comment: I'm already at 6680 and I just finished the Rannoch stuff, so I still have some game left to go. But that's with an imported save and all DLC (except for Eden Prime: Resistance Movement... I missed some data while there so can't complete it). Apparently DLC makes a big difference

Comment: @Sterno: I was at about the same place with close to the same amount, if memory serves.  You'll be somewhere north of 7000 in the end.

Comment: Compiled a list from wikia, but lacks the points to get pass this questions' protection. If I got all the choices right the max you can get is 7730 points without ipad games/multiplayer, assuming you killed Wrex, saved council, and finished all DLC. Without DLC estimated around 7500. Without ME1/2 may drop it below 7000.